# How to override one function from one of the core blocks class?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, core

I need to override one function from the following file:
`Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php`

The function that needs to be overriden is `getJavaScript()`.

I have tried at least three different solutions from SE, however, none of them seemed to produce any outcome.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abstract class **cannot be override in magento**.

If you want to *change the code in **Abstract** class*, There will be a solution that

Copy your file to local codePool.

**Just copy**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
```

**to**

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php
```

and make changes at that local file

Answer (score 2):

You can't rewrite an abstract class because is not instantiated. The rewrite system works because Magento uses a factory pattern to instantiate model, blocks, and helpers

The solution is you should to `override` and not `rewrite` so you copy the file from a `core` to `local` codepool.

Answer (score 1):

Copy this file from `core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php` to `local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Abstract.php` and edit the function in the local copy.